# SQL Server : correct DELETE syntax

Tags: sql-server

I have this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblPricing pricing 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUB_CAR.dbo.CAPVehicles vehicle ON pricing.capid = vehicle.CVehicle_ID
WHERE 
    pricing.[type] = 'car' 
    AND pricing.source = 'ARVAL' 
    AND vehicle.cvehicle_mantext = 'BMW' 
    AND vehicle.cvehicle_modtext = '5 SERIES DIESEL SALOON'  
    AND CVehicle_ManText IS NOT NULL
```

That works fine and I get the correct results.

But, how do I delete that same result set. I tried

```
DELETE FROM tblPricing pricing 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUB_CAR.dbo.CAPVehicles vehicle ON pricing.capid = vehicle.CVehicle_ID 
WHERE 
     pricing.[type] = 'car' 
     AND pricing.source = 'ARVAL' 
     AND vehicle.cvehicle_mantext = 'BMW' 
     AND vehicle.cvehicle_modtext = '5 SERIES DIESEL SALOON'  
     AND CVehicle_ManText IS NOT NULL
```

But that says, incorrect syntax near 'pricing'

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the table alias first. So instead of this:

```
DELETE FROM tblPricing pricing ....
```

this:

```
DELETE pricing 
FROM   tblPricing pricing 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUB_CAR.dbo.CAPVehicles vehicle 
ON              pricing.capid = vehicle.CVehicle_ID 
WHERE           pricing.[type] = 'car' 
AND             pricing.source = 'ARVAL' 
AND             vehicle.cvehicle_mantext = 'BMW' 
AND             vehicle.cvehicle_modtext = '5 SERIES DIESEL SALOON' 
AND             CVehicle_ManText IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing table alias after `DELETE` keyword.

```
DELETE pricing FROM tblPricing AS pricing 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUB_CAR.dbo.CAPVehicles vehicle ON pricing.capid = vehicle.CVehicle_ID 
WHERE pricing.[type] = 'car' AND 
      pricing.source = 'ARVAL' AND 
      vehicle.cvehicle_mantext = 'BMW' AND 
      vehicle.cvehicle_modtext = '5 SERIES DIESEL SALOON' AND 
      CVehicle_ManText IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE P FROM tblPricing  
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUB_CAR.dbo.CAPVehicles vehicle 
ON P.capid = vehicle.CVehicle_ID 
WHERE P.[type] = 'car' 
AND P.source = 'ARVAL' 
AND vehicle.cvehicle_mantext = 'BMW'
 AND vehicle.cvehicle_modtext
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`DELETE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx) statement can optionally have *two* `FROM` clauses. The first is used to identify the table to delete from. The second is used to introduce a `FROM` clause that looks the same as that in a `SELECT` statement. Despite them using the same keyword, they are *not* the same.

If you just have `DELETE FROM xxx` then it's the first variant, and cannot be used to start introducing `JOIN` clauses. So the complete form you want is:

```
DELETE FROM tblPricing --<-- FROM
FROM tblPricing pricing --<-- FROM again. Different feature
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUB_CAR.dbo.CAPVehicles vehicle 
ON pricing.capid = vehicle.CVehicle_ID 
WHERE pricing.[type] = 'car' 
AND pricing.source = 'ARVAL' AND vehicle.cvehicle_mantext = 'BMW'
AND vehicle.cvehicle_modtext = '5 SERIES DIESEL SALOON'
AND CVehicle_ManText IS NOT NULL
```

The other answers have removed the first `FROM` keyword because it is optional (but still, the second type of `FROM` clause has to come *after* the table to delete from has been identified)